# How to show the tooltip without any time duration?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tooltip

I have created a control which i show it as a ToolTip and i update the initial delay and autopopup delay using the below codes,

```
if (this.IsHandleCreated)
{
   //Updates the AutoPopupDelay.
   NativeToolTip.SendMessage(this.Handle, (int)WindowMessages.TTM_SETDELAYTIME, WindowMessages.TTDT_AUTOPOP, new IntPtr(NativeToolTip.MAKELONG(autoPopDelay, 0)));

   //Updates the InitialDelay.
   NativeToolTip.SendMessage(this.Handle, (int)WindowMessages.TTM_SETDELAYTIME, WindowMessages.TTDT_INITIAL, new IntPtr(NativeToolTip.MAKELONG(initialDelay, 0)));
}
```

And it is working fine based on provided delay timings.

But my question is, is there any possibility to show the tooltip without any delay timing?

i.e The tooltip should remain showing until we hide it manually.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Regards,
Amal Raj U.

Comment: i think you dont need tooltip instead you need form like tooltip

Comment: @reds - Can't we achieve this in ToolTip?

Comment: Why  you can't.. it is absolutely could be if you wanted

Comment: Yes, i could not find how to achieve this in ToolTip. Could you please let me know, how to achieve the scenario in ToolTip?

Comment: It's basically use a form, then call a form with its location you want to show.. You can set form background color if you want and you can pass a value too. It's all up to you.

Comment: @reds - Thanks for your response. I am aware of form for this scenario. But Why we can't achieve this scenario in a control?